# Excel 6 Columns Comparison

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am trying to compare 6 columns, 3 columns in the `One Sheet and 3 columns in the`Other Sheet.

Thank you

Comment: Maybe you should provide an easier example. Why is store 4 show not found? I see it on both lists. Try to create a smaller example that is easier to follow.

Comment: Thank you Urdearboy for your comment. Unfortunately the situation is even more complicated, I tired to make it easier in my example. Store 4 is showing "Not Found" because it's not listed in the Inventory Sheet for those items. Orange is not listed in the Inventory Sheet, that's why it's showing "Not Found" for all the Stores in the Orders Sheet. Thank you.

Comment: Agh. Sounds like a job for COUNTIFS which would yield 0 instead of “Not Found” for blank items

Comment: Part of the problem is that many times items are not even listed at all in the Inventory Sheet, while other times are listed only for some stores.

Comment: Then the count will be 0 - I don’t see the problem with that unless I’m missing something

Comment: Unfortunately I am not sure how to do that for all the 6 columns/store/items, returning the exact result (even if it's zero) or returning "Not Found" when an item it's not in the list for a specific store or not listed at all. If an item is listed with zero inventory, it means that there will be inventory available in the following days, if it's not listed, it means that there will be no more inventory at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This needs some re-factoring. This will repeat results for repeated items in orders.It uses dictionaries to hold the sums by stores using the items as keys.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInventoryForListedItems()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim wb As Workbook, orders As Worksheet, inventory As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set orders = wb.Worksheets("Orders")
    Set inventory = wb.Worksheets("Inventory")

    Dim store1Dict As Object, store2Dict As Object, store3Dict As Object, store4Dict As Object, orderList As Object
    Set store1Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set store2Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set store3Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set store4Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set store5Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set store6Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set orderList = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim ordersArray(), inventoryArray(), lastRowOrders As Long, lastRowInventory As Long, i As Long, ordersData As Range

    With orders
        lastRowOrders = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set ordersData = .Range("A2:A" & lastRowOrders)
        Select Case lastRowOrders
        Case Is < 2
            Exit Sub
        Case 2
            ReDim ordersArray(1, 1): ordersArray(1, 1) = ordersData.Value
        Case Else
            ordersArray = ordersData.Value
        End Select

        For i = LBound(ordersArray, 1) To UBound(ordersArray, 1) 'dictionary of the orders to then search for in inventory
            orderList(ordersArray(i, 1)) = vbNullString
        Next
    End With
    With inventory
        lastRowInventory = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Select Case lastRowInventory
        Case Is < 2
            Exit Sub
        Case 2
            ReDim inventoryArray(1, 3)
            inventoryArray(1, 1) = .Range("A2").Value
            inventoryArray(1, 2) = .Range("B2").Value
            inventoryArray(1, 3) = .Range("C2").Value
        Case Else
            inventoryArray = .Range("A2:C" & lastRowInventory).Value
        End Select

        For i = LBound(inventoryArray, 1) To UBound(inventoryArray, 1) 'check if inventory item in orders dictionary
            If orderList.Exists(inventoryArray(i, 1)) And IsNumeric(inventoryArray(i, 2)) Then
                Select Case inventoryArray(i, 3) ' add to dictionaries based on store
                Case 1
                    store1Dict(inventoryArray(i, 1)) = store1Dict(inventoryArray(i, 1)) + inventoryArray(i, 2)
                Case 2
                    store2Dict(inventoryArray(i, 1)) = store2Dict(inventoryArray(i, 1)) + inventoryArray(i, 2)
                Case 3
                    store3Dict(inventoryArray(i, 1)) = store3Dict(inventoryArray(i, 1)) + inventoryArray(i, 2)
                Case 4
                    store4Dict(inventoryArray(i, 1)) = store4Dict(inventoryArray(i, 1)) + inventoryArray(i, 2)
                Case 5
                    store5Dict(inventoryArray(i, 1)) = store5Dict(inventoryArray(i, 1)) + inventoryArray(i, 2)
                Case 6
                    store6Dict(inventoryArray(i, 1)) = store6Dict(inventoryArray(i, 1)) + inventoryArray(i, 2)
                End Select
            End If
        Next
    End With
    With orders
        For i = LBound(ordersArray, 1) To UBound(ordersArray, 1)
            On Error Resume Next
            .Cells(i + 1, 11) = store1Dict(ordersArray(i, 1))
            .Cells(i + 1, 12) = store2Dict(ordersArray(i, 1))
            .Cells(i + 1, 13) = store3Dict(ordersArray(i, 1))
            .Cells(i + 1, 14) = store4Dict(ordersArray(i, 1))
            .Cells(i + 1, 15) = store5Dict(ordersArray(i, 1))
            .Cells(i + 1, 16) = store6Dict(ordersArray(i, 1))
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next
        .Range("E2:J" & lastRowOrders).Replace What:="", Replacement:="Not found"
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi QHarr I hope you can take a look at the new question I posted today. Thank you

Comment: Looks like you have answers. If not,can you edit your question to make clear what is missing still?

Comment: QHarr I uploaded 2 pictures to explain my issue, and one in particular explains why the proposed solutions don't work. My original code works fine in pasting the result in the other Sheet, just it does not fill the other rows below when the macro is repeated. I think it's over writing. Thank you

Comment: I have uploaded another picture to better explain the issue with the solutions proposed by the others.

Comment: Hello QHarr I just posted a new question. I hope you can take a look at it... I posted a picture to explain what I need.